# How can I control for a variable while conducting Wilcoxon Rank Sum Test?

Tags: nonparametric, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test, confounding

I did a Wilcoxon rank sum test to figure out if there is any difference in the distribution of Variable $X_1$ for two groups. The test results showed that the difference does exist.

I, however, suspect that there is a confounding variable $X_2$, which is causing this difference.

How can I control for $X_2$?

---

Example Scenario:
Joe wants to understand if there is any difference in the listening capabilities of Males and Females. Joe thinks that "Age" could be a confounding variable in his study; so he wants to control for "Age". Is there any non parametric test that Joe can conduct?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The generalization of the Wilcoxon-Mann-Whitney 2-sample test and the Kruskal-Wallis $k$-sample test is the proportional odds model.  The PO model allows all the modeling flexibility that regression models support, including covariate adjustment.  Details may be found in my [course notes](https://hbiostat.org/rms).

Comment: Hi Frank, the link seems not working. Also I wonder if there is an R package for that?

Comment: Fixed the link.  See the R `rms` package `orm` and `lrm` functions plus lots of material in the [BBR course](https://hbiostat.org/bbr).